# Возможна ли отправка телеграм ботом сообщения в определенную тему?

Tags: telegram-bot, telegram

Есть телеграм бот, который отправляет значение таблицы при изменении. Возможно ли сделать так, чтобы он отправлял данные не в главную(General) тему, а в определенную? Код написан на гугл скрипт. И если да, то как? Ведь telegram id группы у всех общий

Прикрепляю пример:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В общем, надо сделать так, чтобы бот писал в определенную тему, а не в General